# C# Data Collection v Database lookup - which is the more efficient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I was wondering if I could pick the brains of the community...

In a project I am working on, there is a need to look up a value from a key-value list. This list will not change throughout the life of the software. Lets say as an example the list is thus:

```
ID       Name

1        Apple
2        Orange
3        Pear
4        Banana
```

...and so on.

I am considering two methods of implementing this. The first is to store the list in some sort of (as yet undecided) C# data collection, and then look the required value up at runtime as required. The second method I am considering is storing the list within a database table (SQL Server 2008, since you asked). The application can then access the database at runtime via a stored procedure.

The lookup will occur twice in quick succession following a request made by the user from a web form.

My query is this: Which of these two methods would be the most efficient in terms of processing time?

I realise that there might not be a definitive answer to this question, but I would welcome any comments or thoughts.

Comment: hawk - how often do the contents of the list change?  how often would any changes need to be "seen" by the users?

Comment: Don't think you can get a good answer until we know how big the list will be.

Comment: The list will contain approximately 100 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is expensive in term of performances is usually disk access and network access.

if you have the collection available in memory (RAM) in the web server or application server this would be faster than a query to the database.

if the data is not likely to change often or at all, you can go for in memory data structure, if it changes sometimes you can query from db and store it in the cache so following accesses to that object will not require database query until cache expires or is reset depending on your needs.

Comment: I pretty much thought that this would be the case, but it's great to get some feedback from others. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dictionary<>, it's orders of magnitude faster than a roundtrip to the database.

Comment: I will look into this. If I'm honest I have not been coding with c# for very long, and am still finding my feet. Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: You'll find it in the System.Collections.Generic namespace.

Answer (score 0):

As you state -

> This list will not change throughout the life of the software.

I'd hard code the list into the program. It's not worth the database overhead for a list that will never change.

Comment: I would not hard code it anyway, rather put it in an XML file or similar storage so can be changed without editing too much code ;-)

Comment: That seems sensible, the way your question read I thought it was never going to change.

Comment: I can confirm that the list will not change. The list should convert text terms such as "1 year" into an integer representing the number of whole days within that time frame.